# Javascript - Use onload event , or not

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm coding a script that will be used on several websites as a plugin. I have to use only Javascript, no framework. I'm asking myself, what is the best way to load my script without causing any trouble with other scripts or frameworks that can be loaded on these websites.
I thought to do a global function where i call the functions I want to use, and I put this function on the window.load event, like this :

```
<script>
    var global = function(){
    object.domain.function1();
    object.domain.function2(param1, param2);
    object.domain.function3(1);
}
(function(){
    if(document.addEventListener){
        document.addEventListener('load',global, false);
    }
    if(document.attachEvent){
        document.attachEvent('onload',global);
    }
})();
</script>
```

Or simply :

```
<script>
    object.domain.function1();
    object.domain.function2(param1, param2);
    object.domain.function3(1);
</script>
```

Of course, I need some elements are loaded on my page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2nd. What exactly problems you expect that need to be solved with something more convoluted?

Comment: You should be using `.addEventListener` on `window` not `document` when listening for `'load'`.

Comment: The other event you might be interested in is called [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_(event)) which has target `document`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the best way to load my script without causing any trouble with other scripts or frameworks

The things you need to consider are, are you..

- polluting the namespace
- obstructing another script

The second point is easy to work around, [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) supports adding many listeners for the same event which won't overwrite each other. There are two different events you might be interested in, `'load'` on `window` and [`'DOMContentLoaded'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_%28event%29) on `document`. You can always put a `<script>` at the very end of `<body>` but I personally don't like doing this because you're mixing HTML with JavaScript or changing the DOM tree.

For the first point, this can be done via the use of anonymous functions and, should you need to occupy the namespace, keeping all of your variables and methods inside one object to minimise your impact.

Putting all this together you may end up with something like this

```
var myObjectName = { // everything in one object in global namespace
    domain: {
        function1: function () { /*...*/ },
        function2: function () { /*...*/ },
        function3: function () { /*...*/ }
    }
};

(function (fn) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', fn, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) { // Consider if support for `.attachEvent` is really necessary, people need to move on.
        window.attachEvent('onload', fn);
    }
})(function () { // pass your function anonymously
    myObjectName.domain.function1();
    myObjectName.domain.function2(param1, param2);
    myObjectName.domain.function3(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with putting javascript inside the `<body>` tag then a fairly reliable way of running javascript after the entire page has loaded is placing your javascript in `<script>` tags at the very bottom of the page.

It's not my preferred way of handling this issue, but if using the `onload` event is not working quite right for you this would be a good next step.

Comment: I forgot to tell it but the script can be anywhere in the page, recommended to put it on the bottom like all the javascript files (except google analytics maybe) but it is posible some people will put it at the top in the <head>. So  need an onload event or a domready event, I'm asking what is the best way to do it without conflict with other scripts.

Comment: I'm not really sure how your script could conflict with anything else. If it were going to conflict in any way, it seems to me that it would still conflict while using `onload` or `domready`. I should clarify that I see conflict as "interferes with other existing javascript or causes an error".